# Copy entire cubemap texture from framebuffer

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3, render-to-texture

`glFramebufferTexture` allows one to bind an entire cubemap as a color attachment for layered rendering. In turn, `glReadBuffer` then allows one to bind said entire cubemap as a read buffer.

I want to render a scene to the non-zero mip levels of a cubemap texture. I'm using layered rendering to render not to one face, but to the entire thing in one go. However, the shader used for this uses the 0th mip level of that same texture. Since I don't think I can expose the texture to a shader and to a framebuffer attachment at the same time, I'm rendering to a different texture and copying the contents of that texture to my original texture's desired mip level.

Right now I'm doing this with a pass-through shader, which is pretty slow since it's layered rendering thus uses a geometry shader, and it would be better to use an API function. However, `glCopyTexSubImage2D` only allows cubemap faces, and neither it nor `glCopyTexSubImage3D` seem to accept cubemaps as input. Apart from 4.5-specific functions such as `glCopyTextureSubImage3D`, is there any way to retrieve an entire cubemap from the framebuffer into a cubemap texture ? I'm also aware that `glCopyImageSubData` exists, but something at the feature level of `glFramebufferTexture` is preferrable (so 3.2).

Comment: The only way a framebuffer can be a cubemap is by attaching a cubemap texture to an FBO. So if you do that, the framebuffer contents are already in a texture, and "is there any way to retrieve an entire cubemap from the framebuffer into a cubemap texture" is a non-operation which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In my case, I want to render to the non-zero mip levels of a texture while using the zero mip level of that same texture in the shader used for the rendering. Since I don't think I can just do that, I'm using a temporary texture that I'm rendering to, and then I'm using a pass-through shader to copy the entire cubemap mipmap to my original texture using layered rendering (uses a geometry shader -> slow). I'm looking for a better way to do that copy that doesn't use a geometry shader or 6 bindings, copies and unbindings. I edited the question to clarify the situation.

Comment: Why do you think you can't do that? In reasonably modern GL, you can, as [GL_ARB_texture_barrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_texture_barrier.txt) is in core since GL 4.5.